# no intellisense for controls in Adobe Flash CS 4 Professional

Tags: flash, adobe, intellisense, flash-cs4

i don't have intellisense when writing AS3 script in flash cs4, and it's only for the controls

anybody knows how to enable it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short answer, you don't.

CS4 is as bad as it gets for code completion and syntax highlighting. It won't look into your custom classes/methods, it won't manage correctly the scope of methods, it won't syntax highlight correctly (comments rendered as RegExp, are we joking?).

If you want to code in AS3 try Flex Builder or FlashDevelop

Comment: CS5 is meant to improve this. There are a few things to fill the void however, FlashDevelop is free so I recommend that. FDT plugin for eclipse is awesome but expensive.

Comment: or Textmate if you are on a Mac